# Сумма чётных цифр числа

Tags: python, pascal

Переделать паскаль в питон

- n - исходное число,
- sum - сумма четных чисел.

```
var  
   n: longint;
   sum: integer;
begin
   readln(n);    
   sum := 0;
   while n > 0 do begin
       if n mod 10 mod 2 = 0 then
           sum := sum + n mod 10;
       n := n div 10;
   end;    
   writeln(sum);
end.
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: а четные цифры с начала или с конца?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, не в этом смысле чётных. Там же `n mod 10 mod 2 = 0` в коде.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ах вот оно что))

Comment: https://pas1.ru/even-digits-sum

Answer (score 4):

Вроде как-то так:

```
print(sum(x for x in map(int, input()) if not (x & 1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print("Введите n")
n = int(input())
sum = 0

while n > 0:
    if n % 10 % 2 == 0:
        sum += n % 10
    n //= 10

print(sum)
```

Comment: не имеет смысла использовать 2 деления с остатком в условии `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант:

```py
a = "1234567890588"
b = sum(int(i) for i in a if ord(i) % 2 == 0)
print(a, b)
```

Вывод:

```
1234567890588 36
```

Или одной строкой:

```py
print(sum(int(i) for i in input() if ord(i) % 2 == 0))
```

дополнительный вариант:

```py
print(sum(int(i) for i in input() if i in "2468"))
```